# How to fix the reference error: cannot find variable touchevent using react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to fix the `reference error: cannot read variable TouchEvent`. This error shows up on Safari but not on other browsers.

I am trying to have a method to detect the event and copy the mouse events like below. But somehow on Safari it throws the error as mentioned above when it executes the method below.

```
function copy_mouse_event(event) {
  const event_init = {
    // EventInit
    bubbles: event.bubbles,
    eventPhase: event.eventPhase,

    // UIEventInit
    detail: event.detail,
    view: event.view,

    // EventModifierInit
    altKey: event.altKey,
    ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey
  };

  // initialise MouseEvent data which is shared by wheel, mouse and pointer events
  let mouse_event_init = {};
  if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
    mouse_event_init = {
      ...event_init,
      button: event.button,
      buttons: event.buttons,
      clientX: event.clientX,
      clientY: event.clientY,
      relatedTarget: event.relatedTarget,
      screenX: event.screenX,
      screenY: event.screenY
    };

    if (event instanceof WheelEvent) {
      const wheel_event_init = {
        ...mouse_event_init,
        deltaMode: event.deltaMode,
        deltaX: event.deltaX,
        deltaY: event.deltaY,
        deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
        wheelDelta: event.wheelDelta,
        wheelDeltaX: event.wheelDeltaX,
        wheelDeltaY: event.wheelDeltaY
      };
      return new WheelEvent(event.type, wheel_event_init);
    }
  }

  // try the modern pointer event first, then mouse and touch events
  if (event instanceof PointerEvent) {
    const pointer_event_init = {
      ...mouse_event_init,
      pointerId: event.pointerId,
      width: event.width,
      height: event.height,
      pressure: event.pressure,
      pointerType: event.pointerType,
      isPrimary: event.isPrimary
    };
    return new PointerEvent(event.type, pointer_event_init);
  } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
    return new MouseEvent(event.type, mouse_event_init);
  } else if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {
    //error occurs here only on safari
    const touch_event_init = {
      ...event_init,
      changedTouches: event.changedTouches,
      targetTouches: event.targetTouches,
      touches: event.touches
    };
    return new TouchEvent(event.type, touch_event_init);
  }
}
```

The error occurs only on this line `else if (event instanceof TouchEvent)` and only on Safari. I am not sure how to fix this and why the problem is caused. Could someone provide me an insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `TouchEvent` is not supported by `safari` as per the `TouchEvent` [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/TouchEvent).

Comment: thanks how could i change the code, such that it works for safari and mobile browsers as well.

Comment: Please share you solution @someuser2491.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if TouchEvent exists in window first:

```
const isTouch = 'TouchEvent' in window && nativeEvent instanceof TouchEvent
```